# C++ How to check the latest file exists with thread

Tags: c++, visual-c++, threadpool

Good morning everyone,I'm newbie in C++ (visual studio community 2015), i was wondering need to check the latest text file exists in the directory if no create it, i was using thread to do this because i have others thread running on background doing different kind of job.
I try to put check file isn't exists in the directory on create file method.

**To archive:**

1. set time for thread
2. create file by thread
3. check file is exists, if no re-run the thread.

I do need some help here, thanks.

**Below is my scratch code:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>
#include <mutex>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Shlwapi.h>

using namespace std;

int _times = 10000;  //create file time


template <typename T>
static void __stdcall timer_fired(PTP_CALLBACK_INSTANCE, PVOID context, PTP_TIMER timer)
{
    cout << "Enter Timer Fired--CloseThreadpoolTimer" << endl;
    CloseThreadpoolTimer(timer);
    std::unique_ptr<T> callable(reinterpret_cast<T*>(context));
    (*callable)();
    cout << "Exit Timer Fired--CloseThreadpoolTimer" << endl;
}

template <typename T>
void times(T callable, long long delayInMs)
{
    cout << "Enter times Fired--state" << endl;
    auto state = std::make_unique<T>(std::move(callable));
    auto timer = CreateThreadpoolTimer(timer_fired<T>, state.get(), nullptr);
    if (!timer)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Timer");
    }

    ULARGE_INTEGER due;

    due.QuadPart = static_cast<ULONGLONG>(-(delayInMs * _times));  //10000LL
    FILETIME ft;
    ft.dwHighDateTime = due.HighPart;
    ft.dwLowDateTime = due.LowPart;
    SetThreadpoolTimer(timer, &ft, 0, 0);

    state.release();
    cout << timer << endl;
    cout << "state Release" << endl;
}

void createfile()
{
    cout << "Thread Enter Create File Function" << endl;
    SYSTEMTIME systemTime;
    GetLocalTime(&systemTime);
    FILE *filestream;
    char log_filename[512];


    memset(log_filename, 0, sizeof(log_filename));

    sprintf(log_filename, "D://Log//%04d%02d%02d%_%02d_%02d.log",
        systemTime.wYear, systemTime.wMonth, systemTime.wDay, systemTime.wHour,
        systemTime.wMinute, systemTime.wSecond);

    filestream = fopen(log_filename, "a");

    fclose(filestream);

    // check file start here
    auto filepaths = "D://Log//*.log";
    struct stat result;
    if (stat(filepaths, &result) == 0)
    {
        auto mod_time = result.st_mtime;

    }
    // check file end here

}

void main()
{
    cout << "Thread Pool Start" << endl;

    while (true)
    {
        times(createfile, _times);
        std::cin.get();
    }


}
```

Comment: You should learn the language with a good book beginning with basics not by messing with WinAPI, timers and threads. First, it is `int main()` and `<stdio.h>` is called `<cstdio>`, `<time.h>` `<ctime>` and almost all functions of the standard library are contained in the namespace `std` so either use `using namespace std;` or write eg. `std::cout` and so on. Second: Your code is a mess. `ULARGE_INTEGER due;` is never used and therefore the parameter `long long delayInMs` of `times()` is utterly useless. Also it is not clear, what you want to achieve. Please rephrase your question.

Comment: @Swordfish yes is a mess i agree with you, first create file use thread, second check latest file in order to check if the file is already create